# Extracting a value from a HTML file as an NSString

Tags: html, ios, xcode, nsstring, google-finance-api

I'm creating a currency converter and using the Google Finance API to do so.

[I'm following these simple instructions.](http://oohhyeah.blogspot.com/2009/01/google-currency-conversion-api.html)

The URL outputs a page that looks something like this:

> {lhs: "100 Euros",rhs: "132.240437 Australian dollars",error: "",icc: true}

My question is, what is the best way to extract the outputted value (132.240437) as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use RegEx (e.g. [RegexKit Lite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/)).
For this task you'll need:

```
[respStr stringByMatching:@".*rhs: \"([0-9\-\.]*)" capture:1L];
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? (I get four warnings, "Unknown escape sequence"?)

Comment: NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100EUR%3D%3FAUD"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSString *extractedString = [content stringByMatching:@".*rhs: \"([0-9\-\.]*)" capture:1L];
    NSLog(@"%@", extractedString);

Comment: Don't worry. XCode jut doesn't know escape sequence "\-". You can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Get a simple JSON parser like [this one](http://github.com/stig/json-framework). Then

```
#include "JSON.h"
```

After getting your JSON string called, say, `download` from the API:

```
NSDictionary *currencyData = [download JSONValue];
NSString *numberString = [currencyData objectForKey:@"rhs"];
numberString = [[numberString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
```